# Problem adding a new Window from Library in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode4, interface-builder, uiwindow

I am trying to add a UIWindow through interface builder.
Whenever i drag a window from the library, its default size is 320x480
As I am designing an app for iPad, I want this to be 768x1024
The values are greyed out but changes when resizing with the help of mouse.
Any one had this Issue before?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the device set to iPad in the target section? Did you try to delete the xib and add a new MainWindow.xib.

Comment: Thanks Dasdom... That was it... The XIB was that off iPhone... I created a new one and it all works well.... Can you post it as an answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: Nice. I have edited my first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `UIView`s instead of `UIWindow`s.

Edit: Sorry, didn't read correctly. Here my answer after reading carefully: Is the device set to iPad in the target section? Did you try to delete the xib and add a new MainWindow.xib.

Comment: Actually I am trying to port an iPhone app to iPad. So replacing the Window of the delegate.